# Nesting Models Relations In Forms - Laravel

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, laravel, laravel-4

In laravel, is there some way of nesting related resources in a form?

Say I have this:

```
class Person extends Eloquent {
  public function addresses() {
    return $this->hasMany("Address");
  }
}

class Address extends Eloquent {
  public function person() {
    return $this->belongsTo("Person");
  }
}
```

and I want a `Person` form to collect information about that `Person`'s `Address`es. Does laravel facilitate this in a way that is equivalent to Rails' `accepts_nested_attributes_for :address` and `fields_for :address`?

I'd just like something simple where I can include the `Address` fields with the results of the `Person` form, since the `Address` doesn't really exist apart from the `Person`. Does this make sense?

**== EDIT ==**

*This is hypothetical code*

What I'm looking for is something that would resemble this:

```
{{ Form::model(new Person, array("action" => "admin\PersonController@store", "method" => "POST")) }}

{{ Form::text("name", array(...)) // <input name='person[name]' ... /> }}


{{ Form::email("email", array(...)) // <input name='person[email]' ... /> }}

{{ Form::fields_for("addresses"/* Would be name of relation */) }}

  {{ Form::text("street_address") // <input name='person[addresses][][street_address]' ... /> }}

{{ Form::close_fields() }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're getting at here. Are you after pulling through a list of addresses in to a select box on a form or something? On another note, while you can call your methods pretty much anything when defining relationships, I would name 'persons' to 'person' cause only 1 person belongs to an address and not multiple.

Comment: I'm wanting to create an address at the same time as the Person is created, using the same form.

Comment: `Address::persons` was a typo. Fixed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are on the right track with the input names.

**Form**

```
// Form open, Person fields, etc...

<h2>Addresses</h2>
@foreach ($addresses as $address)

    <fieldset>

        {{ Input::text('addresses['.$address->id.'][address_1]', $address->address_1) }}
        {{ Input::text('addresses['.$address->id.'][address_1]', $address->address_2) }}
        {{ Input::text('addresses['.$address->id.'][city]', $address->city) }}
        {{ Input::text('addresses['.$address->id.'][state]', $address->state) }}
        {{ Input::text('addresses['.$address->id.'][zip]', $address->zip) }}

    </fieldset>

@endforeach

// Form Close
```

If you want to add addresses you'll need to generate some random key to use instead of the address id. This will keep the fields grouped.

**Controller Logic**

This is how I would handle input, using 'fillable' to filter the data going into the models.

```
// Get the Person model, fill, save, etc...

$addressIds = array();
foreach (Input::get('addresses', array()) as $id => $addressData)
{
    $address = Address::find($id) ?: new Address;
    $address->fill($addressData);
    $address->save();
    $addressIds[] = $address->id;
}

$changes = $person->addresses()->sync($addressIds);

// Delete the unused addresses
foreach ($changes['detached'] as $detachedAddressId)
{
    $address = Address::find($detachedAddressId);
    if (!empty($address)) $address->delete();
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't have to 'generate some random key' for a new address, though, right? It'd just be blank, and the code you posted looks like it would handle that just fine.

Comment: Unless you added more than one address. In that event you'd need distinction between those two groups of fields.

Comment: Hmm. I thought it'd end up like `$_FILES`.

Comment: @CollinJames: I want to implement same for Event and Admin (in my example) in which one event can be assigned to multiple admin on the same form (Event create form). But i could not understand from your solution that what i need to write in Create method of my Event controller because after writing the code in View of Event "create.blade.php", i get an error "Undefined Variable admins". Can you please provide a full example that provision to save data for associated table from the parent's table Creation form?

Comment: This solution worked awesome, but what if you want the user to be able to create or delete address objects?

Comment: Creating works with the example as is. sync() returns an array like so... array('attached' => array(), 'detached' => array(), 'updated' => array()). Just use the 'detached' set of ids to delete the unused addresses.

Comment: Hi, Collin! I'm having problems to fill the form when errors are found and I redirect back to create view. How do you deal with this? Thanks!

Comment: Finally! Been looking for this for a couple of days. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the package "modelform" to create a form for various models or even a set of forms for relations.

https://github.com/andersondanilo/modelform

Answer (score 0):

You should manage all of this from your controller. Collect the data from the form and use them as you please:

```
// Controller Code
$person = new Person(array(
    'field_1' => Input::get('field_1'),
    'field_2' => Input::get('field_2'),
    .............
));
$person->save();

$address = new Address(array(
    'field_x' => Input::get('field_x'),
    'field_y' => Input::get('field_y'),
    .............
));
$person->addresses()->save($address);
```

[See it in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

Comment: OK. This makes sense. Next question may be ridiculous, but is there any way to pass the `Address` into the `Person` with the other params to save the keystrokes of instantiating and associating the new `Address`?

Comment: I was writing it in the answer, but then I thought: "it's a `hasMany()` relationship!". You could do it, but you have to find the address you need to output first. Then, pass the second argument to have it autocomplete as such:`{{ Form::text("field_x", $person->address->field_x)}}`