# Laravel 5: Eloquent & form model for business hours

Tags: php, sql, forms, laravel, eloquent

i'm trying to implement business hours for my users. So i have basic users table and user_business_hours table, which looks like this:

```
| id | user_id | weekDay | start_time | end_time | created_at | updated_at |
|---:|---------|--------:|------------|----------|------------|------------|
| 1  | 10      | 1       | 10:00:00   | 12:00:00 | ...        | ...        |
| 2  | 10      | 1       | 13:30:00   | 18:00:00 | ...        | ...        |
```

Now the problem:
How to query this model and setup Form::model() / inputs, that laravel will automatically fill nescessary inputs with provided values whlie updating bussiness hours for particular user?

I was thinking about this input organisation:

```
| ...     | Work From | Work From | add new row |
|---------|-----------|-----------| ----------- |
| Monday  | 10:00:00  | 12:00:00  | +           |
| Monday  | 13:30:00  | 18:00:00  | +           |
| Tuesday | <input>   | <input>   | +           |
```

Note that user can setup as many times for each day as he wants (add new row column).

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: I have not been in this situation myself, yet, but i found this other stacklink which night give a solution. The solution here does not use a Form::model, but a Form::open. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684932/nesting-models-relations-in-forms-laravel

Comment: We had a similar problem and the bad thing is that laravel won't match automaticly array input names. I think that you have to loop over all business_hours ... the problem is the transformKey() method inside the FormBuilder. This transforms every character that can identify an array index/key to an underscore or other sign ... the only way is to transform the model to an array and use the array as the model and then it can match names like "example[0]" to the array element [example => [0 => 'xxx']]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to transform your model to an array:

```
{!! Form::model($model->toArray(), []) !!}
    {!! Form::text('business_hour[0][from]', null, []) !!}
    {!! Form::text('business_hour[0][to]', null, []) !!}
    {!! Form::text('business_hour[1][from]', null, []) !!}
    {!! Form::text('business_hour[2][to]', null, []) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Depending on your array structure - in background the array_get() helper is running and the field names are converted with the transformKey() method.

```
protected function transformKey($key)
{
    return str_replace(['.', '[]', '[', ']'], ['_', '', '.', ''], $key);
}
```

If you deliver the model as an object than everything inside also has to be an object it's not possible to use something like:

```
{
    'key' => [
        'hallo' => 'welt'
    ]
}
```